# Can't display logfiles in Plesk 11

Tags: plesk

If I try to open a log file in Plesk I get an empty popup.
Downloading the logfile is possible.

It's a brand new installed system with Ubuntu 12 and Plesk 11

Answer (score 0):

Parallels has just released a new version of Plesk Mobile Manager that can be used for browsing access and Panel logs via iPad or iPhone. The app works if your Plesk has PowerPack.

Answer (score 0):

Which log files are you trying to open? HTTP? Plesk? Nginx? Php? 
One thing to consider is a service like Splunk. You can have all of your HTTP/Plesk/NGINX/Syslog files via the Splunk service. Then you can view everything in one nice and neat interface.